# Labeling in ImageJ

Tags: background, label, foreground, imagej

I'm new to `ImageJ`, and want to ask about how can I for instance select and label the region of interest (i.e; foreground) with `1`, and the other parts of the image (i.e; background) with `0`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The typical workflow in ImageJ is to first *preprocess* your image to separate foreground from background, then *threshold* to create a binary image mask. You can optionally perform morphological operations to manipulate the mask. Then when finished, convert the mask to a selection, transfer the selection back to your original *unprocessed* image, and measure desired statistics.

Another nice option for segmentation if you are having trouble coming up with effective preprocessing steps is the "Trainable Weka Segmentation" plugin, which uses machine learning with an intuitive user interface to classify image pixels into multiple classes.

For further details on these approaches, see the [Segmentation page](http://fiji.sc/Segmentation) of the Fiji wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Using *Edit > Selection > Create Mask* will create a [binary image](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-29.html#infobox%3ablackBackground) from your selection. In ImageJ, a binary image has only two values, 255 (foreground) and 0 (background). Depending on your settings in [*Process > Binary > Options...*](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-13.html#sec%3aSettings-and-Preferences), these are displayed as black on white or as white on black, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

For labelling objects in the foreground you can use Analyze --> Analayze particles and check "add to Manager" for automatic selection of your ROIs.